# How do I get my list to print out every line?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm a little confused as to why this is not working. I'm trying to get my program to read every line out a csv file change it from a string to a float and then print it out line by line.

```
csv_list = open('example_data.csv','rb')
lists= csv_list.readlines()
csv_list.close()


for lines in lists:
    lists_1 = lists.strip().split()
    list_2 = [float(x) for x in lists_1]
print list_2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure on purpose or not, but you `print` statement is outside of the loop. (Would only print last line.)
You line should also be:
`lists_1 = lines.strip().split()`. otherwise you're always doing the same.

Answer (score 5):

First, don't use `readlines`. Simply iterate over file

```
for lines in csv_list:
   ...
```

second, use csv library for reading http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

In your exapmple, it is csv, so don't split by whitespace but comma or semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pprint

with open('example_data.csv','rb') as csv_list:
    lists= csv_list.readlines()
    lists_1 = []
    lists_2 = []
    for lines in lists:
        lists_1.append(lines.strip().split())
        list_2.append([float(x) for x in lists_1])
    pprint.pprint(list_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for lines in lists:
    lists_1 = lines.strip().split()   # 'lines' here
    list_2 = [float(x) for x in lists_1]
    print list_2 # print your list in a loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`print list_2` needs to be indented to the same level as the rest of the loop and it should be  `lines.strip().split()`

Answer (score 0):

`print list_2` is outside of the for loop. You need to indent it.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the file name, I assume that the fields in your file is separated by comma. If that is the case, you need to split the line using the comma:

```
    lists_1 = lists.strip().split(',')
```

Better yet, use the `csv` module. Here is an example:

```
import csv 

with open('example_data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        line = [float(x) for x in line] # line is now a list of floats
        print line
```